# Does SOAP::Lite can be used for creating document/literal web services?

Tags: web-services, perl, soap, wsdl, soaplite

Does SOAP::Lite can be used for creating document/literal web services ? 
While it does support writing **clients** for an existing document/literal web services 
I cannot find how to created a document/literal **server**.

Is there any other module that enable this ?, it will also be helpful if there is a simple way to generate the WSDL for such a service, I tried using POD::WSDL, but the other side could not access it (while using SOAP::Lite I can use the WSDL)

Thanks

Comment: Pod::WSDL just creates a document from your perl Class - outputing it as a string, usually. You still need to 'serve' it somehow to the client from your webserver (as a .wsdl file). If you're implementing the web-service part from scratch (rather than on top of CGI/mod_perl/NGinX/dancer, etc), then you'll need to add a "route" to serve the .wsdl document. You'd usually have the end-point serve an HTML page which contains human readable documentation, perhaps some test forms, and finally, a link to your WSDL route.

Comment: I have used POD::WSDL with SOAP::Lite, the POD::WSDL was used to generated the WSDLand SOAP::Lite to implement the service however both where RPC/ENCODED

Comment: You've written that `the other side could not access it`. Do you mean the "other side" can't download the WSDL, can't consume it, or doesn't understand it? Doc/Lit services are certainly possible, but I wouldn't use SOAP::Lite. Here someone got it working nicely with XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon - https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=86079

Comment: That's actually a bug report above, but it's not an issue you're likely to have noticed and it has since been fixed.

Comment: I seriously doubt POD::WSDL will be up to creating the WSDL for you; I'd construct it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I think [XML::Compile](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MARKOV/XML-Compile-1.42/lib/XML/Compile.pod), [XML::Compile::SOAP](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MARKOV/XML-Compile-SOAP-3.03/lib/XML/Compile/SOAP.pod) and [XML::Compile::WSDL11](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MARKOV/XML-Compile-WSDL11-3.01/lib/XML/Compile/WSDL11.pod) are the modules you want to use when building a (modern) SOAP server and/or client.

Those modules provide a way to create both SOAP servers and clients. They can work with WSDL files to load definitions automatically, or you can do that manually. They also  support "document" and "RPC" modes.

Another cool feature of these modules is that they can parse the WSDL and (if applicable) XSDs, and generate example Perl data structures from them, so you know what to expect when writing a handler (or want to know what arguments to supply when writing a client).